# Git: Tagging of release vs. sourcecode

Tags: git

I have a general project (lets say Project A) that consists of multiple sub-projects. Every sub-project has its own git-repo and maven-pom. Every sub-project got its own version-number.

Now I want to start git-tagging. Tagging should represent the release of binaries.
So I am not sure about the best strategie.

I will show it by example.

Lets say this structure regarding sources.

**Project A**

- Basics: v0.9
- Server: v2.8
- GUI: v1.0
- Algos: v2.3

And lets make this structure regarding binaries (release of the combined sub-projects).

**Project A**

- Server (uses Basics, Server, Algos): release of 12.12.2019
- Client (uses Basics, GUI): release of 14.12.2019

Should I tag every sub-project with the release-date? Or create some release-version-numbers?

I would appreciate some best practice recommendations.

Comment: I wouldn't tag the subprojects, I would tag **Project A** and create a Manifest containing all the versions of the subprojects =>Like that I can go back to the right version of all of them

Comment: The git-repo is in the subprojects. So I only can tag the subprojects.

Comment: You could do a git-repo with scripts in charge of automatic release. There you could manage your tags => It could also call the other projects, compile them(if necessary) and create a release folder with everything in it.... I guess there are many ways to solve your problem, this is just a subjection that has been very useful to me and my colleagues

Comment: StackOverflow is kind of the wrong place to ask "best practice" questions: it's about solving a particular problem, rather than wise software engineering choices (that's what https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is for).